# Customize displayModeButtonItem Appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, displaymode

I'm trying to use an image for my `displayModeButtonItem` in my `UISplitViewController`. I get the item looking like I want it but it doesn't do anything when tapped on an iPhone. It works fine when using an iPad.

```
UIBarButtonItem *menuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list_button"]
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                           target:self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem.target
                                                           action:self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem.action];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuItem;
```

I've added a check to make sure `displayModeButtonItem` is not `nil` and it is indeed not `nil`.

```
if (self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem == nil) {
    NSLog(@"displayModeButtonItem is nil");
} else {
    NSLog(@"displayModeButtonItem is NOT nil");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to assign another `selector` and `target` for this ? and log if it works ?

Comment: I did that and it works.

Comment: `self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem` is probably `nil` when you create your button on iPhone

Comment: @dan, see my update.

Comment: Probably the action/target is not retained and get's nil when you override the button `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuItem;` Honestly I don't know :)

Comment: @user3351949, I've checked that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:faceImage style:UIBarStyleDefault target:self action:@selector(addProduct:)];
```

Comment: This works, but why would my code work on the iPad but not the iPhone?

Comment: Are you using one storyboard for both devices? Have you cleaned the project and deleted the derived data in a while? What do you mean by not working? Is it not going to the method on the iPhone?

Comment: I'm actually not using a storyboard. By not working, I mean the bar button item to show the master view controller works on the iPad but not on the iPhone after I've implemented the code from my post.